# Even though password is incorrect the user is validated and passes the authentication check in django

Tags: python, django

I am using landsatxplore API to download satellite images and now I am creating a web application to do that using the same API in Django.

In simple python script.

```
from landsatxplore.api import API
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
api = API(username, password)
```

if the username and password are correct it creates an API instance/Key and if the username and password is incorrect it throws an exception:

```
landsatxplore.errors.USGSAuthenticationError: AUTH_INVALID: User credential verification failed.
```

I am trying the same logic in Django but even if I type the wrong username and password it passes the authentication and sends me to the next page homepage.html which should only be accessible if the username and password is correct.

views.py

```
from landsatxplore import errors
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from landsatxplore.api import API


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username == None or password == None:
            messages.info(request,"please Enter the username and password")
    else:
        try:
        # Initialize a new API instance and get an access key   
            api = API(username, password)
        except errors.USGSUnauthorizedError:
            messages.info(request,"Username and password is wrong")
        else:
            return render(request,"homepage.html")
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'homepage.html')
```

HTML:

```
       {% for message in messages %}
       <p>{{message}}</p>
       {% endfor %}
        <form method ="POST" action = "homepage">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>Username:</p>
            <input type = "text" name ="username">
            <p>Password:</p>
            <input type="text" name = "password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
            
        </form>
```

Comment: You probably want to catch `USGSAuthenticationError` (instead of `unauthorized`)

Comment: Yes, USGSAuthenticationError should be caught. But I solved it by separating the login and index page. must have been some cross-connection between the pages

Answer (score 0):

New Views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
       
        if not username or not password:
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            try:
        # Initialize a new API instance and get an access key   
                api = API(str(username), str(password))
            except errors.USGSAuthenticationError:
                messages.info(request,"Username and password is wrong")
                return render(request,"register.html")
            else:
                return render(request,"homepage.html")
    return render(request,"login.html")
```